# how to understand 'notify you twice about a task being interrupted'

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I am read Thinking in Java recently . In 'Checking for an interrupt' chapter, it says 'by calling interrupted( ). This not only tells you whether interrupt( ) has been called, it also clears the interrupted status. Clearing the interrupted status ensures that the framework will not notify you twice about a task being interrupted.'

how to understand this? what is the consequence of notifying interrupted twice?

Comment: The consequence depends on how your application handles interruptions. If you handle them idempotently, it doesn't matter if you are notified twice; similarly, if handled non-idempotently, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give a simple answer because interruptions require cooperation of threads: the consequence depends on how your application handles interruptions.

If you handle them idempotently, it doesn't matter if you are notified twice; similarly, if handled non-idempotently, it does.

As an example, threads have to check if they have been interrupted in order to know they should try to stop what they are doing. You might see something like:

```
if (Thread.interrupted()) {
  throw new InterruptedException();
}
```

The interrupted flag and `InterruptedException` are distinct ways of indicating interruption. Doing it like the above means that only one thing indicates the interruption at the place catching the exception - the fact the exception was caught - so you can completely handle the interruption there and carry on.

If you had used `isInterrupted()` there, which doesn't clear the flag:

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
  throw new InterruptedException();
}
```

You would throw and catch the `InterruptedException`, but the interrupted flag would still be set. If you subsequently invoked something which itself checked for interruption (e.g. `Thread.sleep()`):

```
// Terrible code! This is purely to demonstrate a point.
try {
  try {
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) { // Try replacing with interrupted().
      throw new InterruptedException();
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    System.out.println("I slept, I woke up");
  }
} catch (InterruptedException ee) {
  System.out.println("Oh no not again!");
}
```

that would immediately throw an `InterruptedException` because of the interrupted flag, even if no new interruption actually occurred between the catch and the sleep.